# hyperledger fabric some problem in deploying on kubernetes

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

i have some question.
while deploying fabric-ca 1.4.9, orderer 2.2.1 and peer 2.2.1 in kubernetes with tls configure is enable, i cannot excute command peer channel create following this error.

```
Error: failed to create deliver client for orderer: orderer client failed to connect to orderer.example.com:7050: failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded
```

i executed configtxgen and crypto-gen command before create channel with configtx.yaml and crypto-config.yaml.

Answer (score 0):

Current problems and questions are not specified. To solve this problem, information about the parameter options in the `peer channel create` command is required.

Then, check whether the MSP (crypto) specified in the created configtx.yaml and the policy match well.

- In addition to the above information, it is good to give the topology information of the currently established blockchain network.